# To delete Multiple block of data from a file in perl?

Tags: regex, perl, perl-module, mod-perl, perl-data-structures

```
  <test name="">
  <class name="48.">
  </class>
  </test>
```

The above entry comes in my file for around four times  and I want to remove those entries from the file, so I'm using the following logic:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$count=0;
open (FILE, '/tmp/uday/testng-results.xml');
my@lines = <FILE>;
for(my $i=0;$i<$#lines;$i++)
{
    if($lines[$i] =~ /<test name="">/)
    {
        $count++;
    }
}
print "$count\n";
while($count!=0)
{
    open (FILE, '/tmp/uday/testng-results.xml');
    my  @lines = <FILE>;
    for(my $i=0;$i$#lines;$i++)
    {
        if($lines[$i] =~ /<test name="">/)
        {
            print "Start line number $i\n";
            $Start=$i;
            $End=$i+4;
            print "$End Line number End\n";
            system("sed -i '$Start,$End d' testng-results.xml");
        }
    }
    $count--;
}
```

Is their any better way to do it?

Comment: You should use indentation, it will make your life much easier. And the same goes for `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: Try `perl -ne 'unless (m#<test name=""># .. m#</test>#) { print }' yourfile > newfile`. You really should use a parser, but this quick hack might suffice.

Comment: Thanks, but i don't won't to write it to a new file, i want it to be in original file itself after removing.

Comment: I hate to break it to you, but most of these file operations write to new files. Editing the current file is tedious and fragile. Even with Perl's in-place edit switch `-i`, a new file is written, and then copied over to the old name. Though I make a habit of not recommending the `-i` switch to newbies, as that has a tendency to damage their file system.

Answer (score 0):

Using [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML):

```
open /tmp/uday/testng-results.xml ;
remove //test[@name=""][class[@name="48."]] ;
save :b ;
```